# Font precendence issue

Tags: css

I have the following CSS line:

```
font: 700 0.8rem Verdun, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Arial is chosen, and not until Verdun is loaded;

If I use:

```
font: 700 0.8rem Verdun;
```

Verdun font is loaded, immediately, so there is no broken path.

I want Arial to be used only if Verdun is not found;

Comment: You aren't loading Gotham in that code.

Comment: sorry @Turnip, an editing mistake, because I use both of the fonts, in different situations. I edited.

Comment: Is it works if you use only Verdun with sans-serif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is Verdun included in weight 700 with your @font-face declaration? If not then Arial will be a better match so chosen instead. If you don't declare any weight then the browser has to assume the weight is normal.

An an example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Verdun';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Verdun'), local('Verdun-bold'),
   url('../fonts/verdun-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
   url('../fonts/verdun-700.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}
```

If you didn't specify the weight then Verdun is normal (400) weight, so wont match the style requested by your css.

Comment: including weight in @font-face declaration ? I just a declaration with the fonts with now weight declared; can you give me some examples